# Re-arranging rows dynamically according to newly selected number using Angular2+

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Hi I am trying to re arrange rows of the table when some one selects new row number from drop down.
Following is the code

```
 this.numbers=[
                {value: 1, numval:1},
                {value: 2, numval:2},
                {value: 3, numval:3},
                {value: 4, numval:4},
                {value: 5, numval:5},
                {value: 6, numval:6},
              ]

     <tr *ngFor="let sub of mainlist | let j=index">
          <td>{{sub.name}}</td>
         <td>
         <select  [(ngModel)]="sub.order"  (change)="rearrange(sub.order, mainlist,j) >
           <option *ngFor="let number of numbers" [value]=number.value">{{number.numval}} </options>
          </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

When some one wants to change the order of the rows they select new number from drop down which calls rearrange function in component

```
  rearrange(neworder, mainlist, fromindex)
    for(var i=fromIndex+1; i<=mainlist.length-1; i++) {
     if(neworder > fromIndex){
         mainlist[i].order=i;

       } else {
         mainlist[i].order=i+1;
   }
  }
```

The code above works fine if I select where current number is lower than new selected number and it will change but when current number is higher than selected number it will create duplicate of same number i.e. current number is 2 and want to change it to 4 it will create make both 4.
Please let me know how to fix this so when I select new number from order dropdown it automatically re configures. For example on dropdown current number is 2 I select 4 than 1 stays same, 3 becomes 2, 4 becomes 3 and 2 becomes 4, 5 and 6 do not change. 
Thanks

Comment: In this: `(change)="rearrange(sub.order, mainlist,i)"`, where does the value for `i` come from? Should that be `j`?

Comment: Sorry it was typo I corrected it. Thanks